# WPF HTML5 Canvas Slow Rendering

Tags: wpf, html, performance, canvas, rendering

I am working on some Animations in HTML5 Canvas that are loaded in a Web Browser Control in WPF Application. Ideally Web Browser control should be using same IE 10 engine but my animation loads slowly in an embedded WPF Web Browser Control as compared to IE 10.
Is there some hack around or a solution to this.

Comment: post a minimal code to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0):

WPF Browser runs in a compatible mode. 
Try adding this tag in the  section:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10">
```

Comment: I have already added this tag , it does not render without this tag , by default WPF browser is IE7